# How to user lower() method when filtering pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
             0         1         2         3         4         5
word                                                            
</s>  0.001129 -0.000896  0.000319  0.001534  0.001106 -0.001404
in    0.070312  0.086914  0.087891  0.062500  0.069336 -0.108887
for  -0.011780 -0.047363  0.044678  0.063477 -0.018188 -0.063965
that -0.015747 -0.028320  0.083496  0.050293 -0.110352  0.031738
is    0.007050 -0.073242  0.171875  0.022583 -0.132812  0.198242
```

I have this DataFrame and I want to get rows where index ("word") contains a specific string (case invariant). I've tried

```
df[df.index.str.lower().contains("lebron") == True]
```

it gives `KeyError: False`. Though

```
df[df.index.str.contains("Lebron") == True]
```

works fine.

How to use `lower()` in this case?

Comment: you don't need lower to mention as default its case sensitive that's why it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would suggest not using regex comparisons (i.e., not using `str.lower` with regex) if you are doing simple substring checks. You can use a list comprehension here:

```
df[['lebron' in x.lower() for x in df.index]]
```

If NaNs are possible in the index, you can modify your solution to handle them:

```
df[[pd.notna(x) and 'lebron' in x.lower() for x in df.index]]
```

---

Without regex, `str.contains` can be used accordingly:

```
df[df.index.str.lower().str.contains("lebron", regex=False)]
```

The trailing `== True` can be omitted if you do not have NaNs. Otherwise,

```
df[df.index.str.lower().str.contains("lebron", regex=False) == True]
```

Will work fine.

Comment: Wow. This not only contains the answer but also answers something I was looking for (list comprehension in filtering). But just to be fair, I'm gonna accept @jezrael's answer because he was first and technically gives the correct answer. But I'm gonna upvote this. Thank you very much.

Comment: @jezrael Tis the season to be happy... +1 from me to you :)

Comment: Season of giving :-) +1 to both answers !

Comment: @pygo - merry xmas/ happy hanukah / happy kwanzaa!

Comment: @coldspeed, Very merry xmas!

Comment: @coldspeed, trying to understand other words & meaning apart from merry xmas :-)

Comment: @coldspeed - For you too +1

Answer (score 3):

`lower` is here not necessary, add parameter `case=False` in [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for non case sensitive search and `na=False` if possible missing values and also `regex=False` if no regex search:

```
df[df.index.str.contains("lebron", case=False)]

df[df.index.str.contains("lebron", case=False, na=False, regex=False)]
```

But if want it only chain `str.lower()` with `str.contains()`, also comparing with `True` is not necessary:

```
df[df.index.str.lower().str.contains("lebron")]

df[df.index.str.lower().str.contains("lebron", na=False, regex=False)]
```